# Select JTree node from JComboBox and vice versa

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox, jtree

I have JTree and JComboBox in my application. When I select a node, JComboBox content also changes, but I need to do same thing in case of selecting JComboBox  item.

As you see, if I select "Default Session Start" , the same node should be selected in the JTree. Could someone tell me, what will be a good approach for it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtqqp.png)

Comment: With the Model-View-Controller paradigm on would hold the model (selected node) in the controller. And the controller adds change listeners to (the datamodels of) the views (tree and combobox). In the listeners the controller can then select in every view if it is not already selected.

Comment: Can you provide some code examples?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a part of a skeleton of an application. Swing is rather verbose, and much you'll need to work out. You provide data models for the JComponents, and need to add listeners, or

```
JComboBox<Thing> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(controller.getComboBoxModel());

JTree tree = new JComboBox<>();
... tree.setSelectionModel(controller.getTreeSelectionModel());

publi class Controller { // or Application

    public static void main(String[] args) { ... }

    // Model:
    private ComboBoxModel<Thing> comboBoxModel;
    private TreeSelectionModel treeSelectionModel;

    public Controller() {
        comboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel() {
            @Override
            pubic void setSelectedItem​(Thing item) {
                if (!item.equals(getSelectedItem())) {
                    super.setSelectedItem(itenm);
                    treeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(...);
                }
            }
        };
        treeSelectionModel = new DefaultTreeSelectionModel ...

        ...
    }
```

Important is that there is no back-and-forth setting the selected item, for an unchanged item. Hence the equality test.

Comment: Thank you Joop Eggen for your Answer, I have implemented the Controller class and set selection model, as in your example. There is a problem, that setSelectedItem() method was not called , when I select a node :)

Comment: In the combobox? In the tree you must look for the selection of TreePath.